# css transform origin gets overwritten with rotate

Tags: css, transform

I'm looking into CSS transforms and I cant get this one part to work.

```css
#photo-container img {
  transition: transform 2s, transform-origin 2s;
}

#container-1 img:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

#container-2 img:hover {
  transform: rotate(1.5turn);
  transform-origin: 50%, 50%;
}
#container-3 img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-container" id="container-1">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
    <div class="grey"></div>
    <a href="#" class="button">epicface</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The three classes HTML elements are the same as the one posted below. 
My question is that say I change the transform origin to 0 0, and it has a transform set to rotate, when the rotate occurs and finishes, instead of returning to its original position the same way it did to get there, it recenters itself, then goes to that point that was specified in the rotate function and does it from there.

Is there something I missed here or is this the normal functionality?

Edit. i stuffed something up. sorry to bother

Comment: This is unclear. What do you mean, "instead of returning to its original position the same way it did to get there"? The transform-origin is the center of rotation, which by default is equivalent to `transform-origin: 50% 50%`. By setting it to `0 0`, it's rotating around a point at the top left corner.

Comment: what I mean is that, if I set its origin to 0 0, that's the top left the corner, it will go there, but when it comes back to the origin, it does so by setting the origin to 50% 50% and then rotating it back, so the pivot has moved.

Comment: Which browser are you using? It rotates at 0 0 for me in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `transform-origin` to images without `hover`. And change `#photo-container` to `.photo-container` I can't see another problem with it.

```css
.photo-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.photo-container img {
  transition: transform 2s, transform-origin 2s;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

#container-1 img:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#container-2 img:hover {
  transform: rotate(1.5turn);
}

#container-3 img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-container" id="container-1">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
    <div class="grey"></div>
    <a href="#" class="button">epicface</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="photo-container" id="container-2">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
    <div class="grey"></div>
    <a href="#" class="button">epicface</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="photo-container" id="container-3">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
    <div class="grey"></div>
    <a href="#" class="button">epicface</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how this answer the question ?

Comment: can you explain me then ? :)  you have changed the CSS and thus changed the behavior of his code so what was the issue .. as i didn't understand what he meant

Comment: @TemaniAfif The question was about images not returning to initial position. I have changed the code a bit, and checked it in several browsers. It works well.

Comment: well, still didn't understand. In his code the image also return to its initial place and in yours too, simply with a different manner ... anyway, his question is unclear